# Increasing MySQLD SuperUser Slots

Tags: linux, mysql

In my office we sometimes have servers that hit the max_connections limit.   As we sometimes have scripts that take up that 1 extra 'superuser' slot for MySQLD, we'd like to raise that.

Google really hasn't turned up much on this, is there a way to raise the number of slots?

Comment: How about setting max_connections reasonably high? Do the scripts *realy* have to have superuser rights?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate the following options:

- increasing max_connections to a reasonable amount
- timing out idle connections
- using persistent connections